# Select rows from two different tables but order by date using php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have two tables;

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

I'm trying to produce a statement (like a bank statement) to show all charges and all payments. The charges and payments need to be displayed in date order based on the statement_date field.

I'm pretty sure I need to use 'unions' but I just can't seem to find a solution.

My effort so far is;

```
$statement_sql = "(SELECT * FROM accounts_tenant_charge)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM accounts_tenant_payment)
ORDER BY statement_date";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have just added my query so far, thanks.

Comment: what error do you have with this statement ?

Comment: No pictures thanks. Just proper DDLs

Comment: I assume your tables look like you presented. Then you cannot union two results sets with different number or types of columns.

Comment: @xNeyte No error just no rows are returned.

Comment: @Strawberry Can you please explain what you mean by proper DDLs?

Comment: Strictly speaking, a DDL is a Data Definition Language statement (like "CREATE TABLE my_table..."). I use the term to include certain DML statements (like "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES..." and "UPDATE my_table SET x = 'y'"). Basically, I think of a DDL as anything you might put in the left hand window of an SQLFIDDLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help. The following query worked for me;

```
SELECT tenant_charge_date as statement_date, tenant_charge_id as reference, tenant_charge_total_amount as debit, NULL as credit, 'Charge' as type FROM accounts_tenant_charge
UNION ALL
SELECT tenant_payment_date as statement_date, tenant_payment_id as reference, NULL as debit, tenant_payment_amount as credit, 'Payment' as type FROM accounts_tenant_payment
ORDER BY statement_date
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be make nested query. Firstly, you make union query based on your tables and put in inside query. Then, you make SELECT query and put in outside. Don't forget to give alias table for outside query.

You can try this code :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  (SELECT * FROM accounts_tenant_charge)
   UNION
  (SELECT * FROM accounts_tenant_payment)
) a 
ORDER BY a.statement_date ASC
```

Comment: This code didn't work unfortunately. It didn't display an error but didn't display any rows either.

Comment: Please make sure your column select. Don't use select * in inside query if you have different number of column

Answer (score 0):

Your tables have different number of columns, therefore you cant union them right away by doing a `select *` . You have to select an equal number of columns from both tables. Like:

```
select
  tenant_charge_id as `id`,
  tenant_charge_date as `date`,
  tenant_charge_total_amonunt as `amount`
union
select
  tenant_payment_id,
  tenant_payment_date,
  tenant_payment_amount
order by
  `date` asc
```